# Export the data into a different directory from /tmp/filename.csv in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I have table `emp`. I would like to export all the data into a CSV file in a different directory from the `/tmp/filename.csv` in Ubuntu using MySQL Workbench.

This query is working fine but I want to change the location.

```
SELECT id, name INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM emp;
```

Comment: I use [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) to export the data in CSV as well as export the resultset in CSV format obtained after executing a query to any file specified by you.This tool has helped me to cut the time spent in writing queries to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can store your backup file only the directory on which mysql user has permission, normally mysql user have permission either mysql data directory or /tmp partition where mysql create/store temporary files.

So for different directory first you have to give permissions, you can follow below steps-

create a directory for backup like-

```
mkdir /root/backup
```

give permission like-

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /root/backup
```

Now you can export in `/root/backup`

Try it if you face any issue then revert.

Comment: from root user on linux server.

Comment: when i am going with the above command getting and error for the 2nd command "operation not permitted"

Comment: have you connected your linux machine with root user?

Answer (score 0):

change the OUTFILE attribute:

```
SELECT id, name INTO OUTFILE '/<where_ever_you_want>/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM emp ;
```

Make sure, that the directioy `<where_ever_you_want>` exists and the user has write previleges.

Comment: when i giving any other location getting error "error code 1 ->cant create a file such file or directory" and "errore code 2-> no such directory"

Comment: @KaranKumarMahto looks like your directory does not exists.